# Photoswipe: How to show captions for a photo that doesn't have a thumb on display page

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I have a very simple Photoswipe gallery on this page: http://neighborhoodpets.wink1733.com

How do I add a caption to a photo that does not have a thumb showing on the home page?

I only want it to show when the Photoswipe gallery is activated.

Right now the second image of "Snoop Ray" doesn't have a caption.

Thank you for any advice on solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `data-title` attribute on the second Snoop Ray `a` element like so:

```
<a data-title="Snoop Ray 4877 Jewell" href="images/snoopRay02_lg.jpg" itemprop="contentURL" data-size="750x1334" data-med="images/snoopRay02_med.jpg" data-med-size="750x1334" title="Snoop Ray" data-author="Todd Ray" alt="Snoop Ray"></a>
```

Then, in your script, change this:

```
// create slide object
item = {
    src: el.getAttribute('href'),
    w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
    h: parseInt(size[1], 10),
    author: el.getAttribute('data-author')
};
```

to this (only insert a `title` line):

```
// create slide object
item = {
    src: el.getAttribute('href'),
    w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
    h: parseInt(size[1], 10),
    author: el.getAttribute('data-author'),
    title: el.getAttribute('data-title')
};
```

**And that's it!**

For the second Snoop Ray image, the caption will now be `Snoop Ray 4877 Jewell` plus the author, while not changing the other pictures captions.

Indeed (in case you're wondering), in your script, this sets their captions to the picture title located in the `figure` element:

```
if(childElements.length > 0) {
  item.msrc = childElements[0].getAttribute('src'); // thumbnail url
  if(childElements.length > 1) {
      item.title = childElements[1].innerHTML; // caption (contents of figure)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Works perfectly now.  sw